# How create custom listener in libGdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

How do I create my own EventListener?
I need a specific event to happen when a variable reaches a specific value.

I do not know what information still needs to be given

Comment: What sort of event? What is the source of the event? What type of listener?
You'll need to provide more information in order for us to be able to answer with any accuracy.

Comment: I seem to have written. I need certain actions to be triggered when the value of a variable is changed. I think this should be inherited from EventListener

Answer (score 0):

You don't need EventListener for this. You can simply check it in `render()` function if it is enough to check value each time frame is rendered.

If this isn't enough, you will have to create your own class, which implements setter, which checks if new value matches your condition and executes event.